# How to use mobile: startActivity with OptionalIntentArguments?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

After updating my Appium dependency to version 9.1.0, I am no longer able to use `((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivty(activity)` : https://github.com/appium/java-client/pull/2036

With Appium version 8.5.1, I was able to start my Android Activity like so

```
  Activity activity = new Activity("com.android.settings", ".applications.InstalledAppDetails")
      .setOptionalIntentArguments("package:com.android.chrome");
  ((AndroidDriver) DriverManager.getDriver()).startActivity(activity);
```

How can I launch the `package:com.android.chrome` activity using `mobile: startActivity`?

The package:com.android.chrome should open on the Android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `java-client v9.1.0` dependency you can pass the `package:com.android.chrome` as a URI argument.

```java
driver.executeScript("mobile: startActivity",
ImmutableMap.of( "action", "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS", 
"uri","package:com.android.chrome"));
```

`mobile: startActivity` arguments: https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver?tab=readme-ov-file#mobile-startactivity